# Multiple times login faild occurs because of previous login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, push-notification, session-cookies

I am working an ionic-1. In my project I have to send push notification so I refereed the [ngCordova pushnotification](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) and added this code provided by this website to my page.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    $cordovaPush.register(iosConfig).then(function(deviceToken) {
      // Success -- send deviceToken to server, and store for future use
      console.log("deviceToken: " + deviceToken)
      $http.post("http://server.co/", {user: "Bob", tokenID: deviceToken})
    }, function(err) {
      alert("Registration error: " + err)
    });


    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
      if (notification.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(notification.alert);

         //HERE ONLY I HAVE WRITTEN MY LOGIN LOGIC I HAVE PROVIDED PLUNKER BELOW

      }

      if (notification.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
      }

      if (notification.badge) {
        $cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber(notification.badge).then(function(result) {
          // Success!
        }, function(err) {
          // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
        });
      }
    });

    // WARNING! dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
    $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
    });

 }, false);
```

InOrder to get my mobile device id I used this code take a look at my login.js file in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7uX0xS?p=catalogue).

**PROBLEM I'M FACING:**

1) Imagein we will login in my login page for three times (2 times wrong and 1 time correct).

In my login page at **first time** I have login with **wrong** one I am getting alert success fully **login failed**

Now I am trying to login with correct login **second time** so that page goes to the **correct** login no problem.

Now I am trying **third time** login  with **wrong** username and password but I am I am getting two times login failed to alert and then I am redirected to next page.

**Note:** the third time login I was giving wrong one but I am redirecting to the next page and also I am getting two times login failed error

I think what I have done before is also stored somewhere so that each time when I login it also giving the same previous status to the login page.

Here my console.log output of what I am taking so far as [image] 
At the third time when I login, my logs look above pic.

***NOTE: HERE '0' means login failed and "1" means login success. so why I am getting two times '0' on the third time when I login and one-time login success and the page redirected to home page.***

2) Imagine I am in **home page** now when i click the **device back button** i am **redirected to login page** but it should not directly go to that page I need **some alert to logout** if the device back button is clicked only on home page.

3) when i am refreshing my app i am redirected to login page and my saved data is been lost any help to make my current page be stay login and save data.

I have gone through may blogs and tutorial but not able to understand the third question and second question above.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you the quick answer for point three while I am working on 1 and 2.

When you successfully logged in you should store user information in local storage
$window service.

here is the code snippet

```
var storage = $window.localStorage;
function login()
{
  storage.setItem('isuserloggedin', JSON.stringify('true'));
}
function isUserLoggedIn()
{
  var item = storage.getItem('isuserloggedin');

  if (item) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Unable to parse " + key + " settings.  Returning undefined.")
    }
  }
  else {
    return 'false';
  }
}
function clear() 
{
  storage.clear();
}
```

1. Call login() function just after user successfully logged In.
2. Every Time user open the app(Even after killing that app) just check
   isUserLogedIn().
3. just after user logged out call clear() function.

**Like this you can store user's information in local storage and use it further,by doing this this information will exist in app(even after killing the app) until user logged out**

P.S. Keep the above snippet code in a service or factory so that you can call these functions from anywhere just after injecting the service.

Comment: i have not used a function inside a service can you update you function inside a service i dont know how to use it in service